# How to set a boundary condition while using model.predict in scikit-learn for random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction

I am predicting using [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor`. But how can I set some boundary conditions to make the prediction more accurate?

Line of code for prediction:

```
df_predict['bias_pred_rf'] = rf_model.predict(df_predict[['A', 'B', 'C']])
```

Here, I am enforcing the condition that when 'C' is less than or equal to 0, the 'bias_pred_rf' value should be 0, thus applying the boundary condition.

```
df_predict.loc[df_predict['C'] <= 0, 'bias_pred_rf'] = 0
```

But this I am doing after the prediction. How can I do this in the prediction stage to make the predictions more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom prediction function or a wrapper class. Here's an example using a custom prediction function:

```
import numpy as np

def predict_with_boundary(model, X):
    # Make the predictions
    predictions = model.predict(X)
    
    # Apply the boundary condition
    predictions = np.where(X[:, 2] <= 0, 0, predictions)
    
    return predictions
```